# How to remove glyphs from inherited winform

Tags: vb.net

I created a form with some controls on it. I planned to use the forms for many other projects. However, when I use `inherits` to inherit the original form, it shows glyphs i.e the boxes attached to the controls of the inherited form, like this:

[image: screenshot].

I to want it to show the symbols as it makes the form to look rough. How can I program the original form so that it wouldn't give me those symbols in subsequent forms. An example of what I want is the [MetroUI Framework Design](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework)

Comment: What do you mean by "glyphs", exactly? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I'd attached it. Anyway, I've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: That's the `Inherited Control` Symbol (overlay Icon). It lets you know when a Control is inherited. Those you add to the inherited Form don't show that icon. You see that in the Form's Designer. The *comparison* with the MetroFramework compiled assemblies is not exactly related.

Comment: I see. But I do i make it like MetroFramework compiled assemblies?

Comment: @OlayinkaAjewole Why not just use MetroFramework instead of doing it yourself? But then, why use WinForms? WinForms does NOT work well with animation and does not make it easy to meet today's UX expectations. Why can't you use WPF instead?

Comment: @Dai The MetroFramework has many features I don't need and I don't want its DLLs to add too much size to my Application as most of the features are useless to my project. As for WPF, I've never ventured into it. If I may ask you, can I create a form with WPF and use it in WinForms?

Comment: No, WPF and WinForms are incompatible.

Comment: There is some cross-compatibility, but it might only be at the control level and not the form/window level.